# AngularJS - Sort array inside service, retain binding in controller/view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, firebase

I'm looking for a way to sort an array inside an Angular service, and still retain the correct bindings in the controller.

If I skip the sorting, the bindings work great, but the array isn't ordered as I need it to be.

Whenever I perform the sort using Lodash's `_.sortBy` or angular's `$filter('orderBy')` service, one of two things happens:

1. The array in the service is sorted correctly, but the binding to the controller is severed due to it no longer referencing the same array anymore.
2. If I attempt to fix this by using Lodash's `_.cloneDeep` or angular's `angular.copy`, the browser freezes due to circular references (?).

**Service.js**

```
    angular.module('exampleapp')
.factory('ClientFeedService', function($filter, $firebase, FIREBASE_URL, FeedItemService) {

  return function(clientId) {

    var ClientFeedService = this;
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'feeds/clients/' + clientId);
    var initialDataLoaded = false;
    ClientFeedService.feedArray = [];

    ClientFeedService.sortItems = function() {
      // Sorting logic here
    };


    /**
     * Bind to the initial payload from Firebase
     */
    ref.once('value', function() {

      // Sort items after initial payload
      ClientFeedService.sortItems();
      initialDataLoaded = true;
    });


    /**
     * Bind to new items being added to Firebase
     */
    ref.on('child_added', function(feedItemSnap) {
      console.log('child_added');
      ClientFeedService.feedArray.unshift(FeedItemService.find(feedItemSnap.name(), feedItemSnap.val()));

      // Sort after new item if initial payload loaded
      if (initialDataLoaded) {
        ClientFeedService.sortItems();
      }
    });

    ClientFeedService.getFeedItems = function() {
      return ClientFeedService.feedArray;
    };

    return ClientFeedService;
  };

});
```

**Controller.js**

```
    app.controller('ClientsFeedCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, ClientFeedService) {

  var clientId = $stateParams.clientId;
  $scope.clientFeed = new ClientFeedService(clientId).getFeedItems();

});
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use the orderBy filter on the ng-repeat directive in the view?

Comment: Since you're already using AngularFire(`$firebase`), can't you use Firebase's native `orderByChild` method and then `$asArray()` to get an array that you can bind to `$scope`?

Comment: @Beartums, I was trying to avoid that because using filters directly in the view can be detrimental to performance (they are called multiple times each digest cycle, rather than on-demand in the controller / service).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, the firebase ref that is being set up is only an index, and doesn't contain the actual data that would be needed to use Firebase's native orderByChild, it calls the FeedItemService to fetch the item ids within the index.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that you can solve this.  First, let's look at what is happening.

You are assigning the initial array to `$scope.cliendFeed`.  After this, as data is added, a new Array is being generated and stored in the Service, but you still have a reference to the original Array.  So ultimately, what you want to do is find a way to keep `$scope.clientFeed` in sync with your service.

The simplest solution is probably to use a getter method instead of storing a reference to the array in your scope.

In order to do this, you would have to add something like this:

```
var service = new ClientFeedService(clientId);
$scope.getClientFeed = function () {
  return service.getFeedItems();
};
```

And make sure your `ng-repeat` called this function:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in getClientFeed()">...</li>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: your suggest make possible this [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig)

Comment: Not in the context of this app.  A getter function is fine as long as it is returning the same content each time it is called.  What is NOT okay is if your getter is returning new objects each time it is called.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can push the new data returned from API to the same array in the controller and then apply the *$filter*
2. Here is example

   ```
   function getData(){
      $scope.array.push(returnData);
      sortArrayList($scope.orderByField, $scope.reverseSort);
   }

   function sortArrayList(orderByField, reverseSort){
      $scope.array = $filter('orderBy')($scope.array, orderByField, reverseSort);
   }
   ```